# This function is only working sometimes

Tags: php

```
function getYoutubeVideoId($url) {
    $urlParts = parse_url($url);

    if($urlParts === false)
        return false;

    if(isset($urlParts['host']) && strtolower($urlParts['host']) === 'youtu.be')
        return ltrim($urlParts['path'], '/');

    if(isset($urlParts['query'])) {
        parse_str($urlParts['query'], $queryParts);

        if(isset($queryParts['v']))
            return $queryParts['v'];
    }

    return false;
}
```

This function works great.. unless you use `youtu.be/*` without `http://`

Why does it not work if it is just `youtu.be` or `www.youtu.be` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function getYoutubeVideoId($url) {
    $url = str_replace('http://', '', $url);
    $url = str_replace('www.', '', $url);
    $urlParts = parse_url($url);

    if($urlParts === false){
        return false;
    }

    if(strstr($urlParts['path'], 'youtu.be')){
        return str_replace('youtu.be/', '', $urlParts['path']);
    }

    if(isset($urlParts['query'])) {
        parse_str($urlParts['query'], $queryParts);

        if(isset($queryParts['v'])){
            return $queryParts['v'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically, `youtu.be/foo` is not a URL. A URL must have a scheme at the start, followed by `://`.

So the reason it isn't working is because you're giving the `parse_url` function invalid input. You must clean it up first.

Answer (score 1):

Look what it returns for that input:

```
php> =parse_url('youtu.be/id')
array(
  "path" => "youtu.be/id",
)
```

Perhaps if `host` isn't set on the result, try re-parsing with `http://` prepended.

Answer (score 0):

I just use:

```
function getYoutubeId($url){
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parsed['query']);
    return $v;
}
```

Not sure if that helps...

Comment: This won't get the video ID from youtu.be links.

Answer (score 0):

The [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function specifically does not validate the url, which is why your code would break.

Try using [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and a regex to validate the url first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(
    (isset($urlParts['host']) && strtolower($urlParts['host']) === 'youtu.be'))
    ||
    (!isset($urlParts['host'] && strstr($urlParts['path'],'/',true)=='youtu.be')
```